# Sequence problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Help for this problem would be much appreciated, as I am expected to solve it without being properly taught how.

Suppose a single cell of bacteria divides into three every 12 hours. Suppose that the same rate of division is maintained for 7 days. Give a sequence that lists the number of cells after 7 days.

Answer options:
[image]

Comment: Follows the pattern: n_1*3=n_2, n_2*3=n_3, n_3*3=n_4...

The answer is C.

Comment: As @JasonChen notes, you have to consider how many values are required to represent 7 days of division. The solution requires the combination of your pattern (shared by B and C) plus the insight per JasonChen

Answer (score 1):

The equation is B = A*X^(T*24/H) where B is the number of bacteria. Plug in the values, and you will get answer C, because the bacteria splits every twelve hours, or twice per day. Answer C has the right values that all fit into the function.

Explanation: A is the initial number of bacteria. X is the number of bacteria a single one splits into. T is the time in days, and H is the number of hours it takes for a bacteria to split. Because every bacteria divides at the same time, the function is exponential.

Comment: Oops mistake. Changing 24/H to H/24.

Comment: I think I might have a problem here somewhere...

Comment: try ^((T*24)/H)

Comment: you should edit your answer to give the correct answer, C

Answer (score 0):

With leaps of twelve hours each, the sequence is:

$$1\,,\,3\,,\,9\,,\,27\,,\,\ldots$$

You have the model of the first elements, and this is clearly a geometric sequence, thus...

Answer (score 0):

the following table shows how much bacteria there are now, vs. how many there will be in 12 hours. Complete the table.

\begin{array}{|l|cr|}
\hline
now & in\:12\:hours\\
\hline
1 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 9\\
\hline
9 & 27\\
\hline
27 & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
? & ?\\
\hline
\end{array}